# Scrollbar in flex only when needed?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to set  horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.ON; only when my content exceeds the stage. If my stage width= 400 that can bear only two videocontainer, so the third video is cut off in stage. To avoid this, i put the code like this 
               if(no of video container > 2){
                    horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.ON;
               } 
               else{
                    horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.OFF;
               }
  The above logic works for me. But what i need is:  when the video containers exceed for any stage width, the scroll should come..Otherwise it should in OFF state.
 How to achieve this? Nothing works till now. Anybody please help me ....

Comment: If you were to share some code, it may be easier to help you.  Specifically; what are your containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ScrollPolicy.AUTO
```

> ScrollPolicy.AUTO ("auto") - the scroll bar is displayed when the
>   viewport's contentWidth is larger than its width.

Comment: Hi, I don't need scrollbar when i open the application. But Only I need it when i add contents dynamically especially when the adding contents couldn't fit inside the stage

Comment: That's what I was talking about. ScrollPolicy.AUTO will display the scroll bar only when it is required (I gave you the description from Adobe's docs). Try, please

Comment: Thanks Max Golovanchuk for the description